# Numpy argsort instability

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, numpy, quicksort

Lately,  I have been experimenting **np.argsort** and I have realized something weird.

If you run the following code, you will get the result:

```
In [0]: np.argsort([3]*16)
Out[0]:
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
      dtype=int64)
```

But if you make just a little change:

```
In [1]: np.argsort([3]*17)
Out[1]:
array([ 0, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9, 15,  8,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  7, 16],
      dtype=int64)
```

I know the default method for *numpy argsort* is *quicksort*, which is an unstable sorting algorithm. But, **there is an reasonably explanation about the differents behavior above? Is this related to quicksort's choice of pivot? If so, why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong as I didn't look into it too deeply but it seems numpy uses a *introsort* kind of hybrid algorithm resorting to *insertion sort* (which is stable) for small ranges.

Guess looking at the [code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/2bacec9ecb0fc665117a22027b73812509a99f56/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c.src) should give you a better insight. Look at the different paths the code can follow, `SMALL_QUICKSORT` should be the magic number you're looking for.